# Rails incorrect action call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have some simple actions which I want to call via js but got strange error, here is my code:

Controller:

```
class Admin::CEventsController < Admin::BaseController
  def add_speaker
    # speakers = session[:speakers] ? [] : session[:speakers]
    # speakers << Partner.find(params[:id])
    # session[:speakers] << speakers.uniq
    # @speakers = Partner.find(session[:speakers])
    # puts @speakers.inspect
  end

  def remove_speaker
    # speakers = session[:speakers]
    # speakers.destroy(params[:id])
    # session[:speakers] = speakers
    # @speakers = Partner.find(session[:speakers])
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :c_events,         :except => [:show] do
      member do
        post :add_speaker
        post :remove_speaker
      end
    end
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <% speakers.each do |p| %>
      <p><%= link_to p.name remove_speaker_admin_c_event_path(p), :method => :post, :remote => true %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <% Partner.all.each do |p| %>
      <p><%= link_to p.name, add_speaker_admin_c_event_path(p), :method => :post, :remote => true %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I commented some of actions code just to try to find the problem.
The error I got is:

> Started POST "/admin/c_events/2/add_speaker" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2014-01-06 21:38:25 +0200 Processing by
>   Admin::CEventsController#add_speaker as JS   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
>   CEvent Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "c_events".* FROM "c_events" WHERE
>   "c_events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]] Completed 404 Not Found in
>   12ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find CEvent with id=2):

Seems like another actions is called, another actions in this controller is standard CRUD rails acctions

Comment: The desired action looks like it is indeed being called correctly, as evidenced by this in your log output: `Processing by Admin::CEventsController#add_speaker`. Are there any `before_filter` in the `Admin::CEventsController` or `Admin::BaseController` controllers that could be trying to load a `CEvent` object?

Comment: It looks like you pass wrong ID parameter.

Comment: @Teeg I have an before_filter in Admin::BaseController but it just sample devise authorization (current user has admin rights). I cannot identify where controller try to load CEvent object. here is the full controller code http://upl.io/dx69ll

Comment: @maki Hmm, odd. I assume there was a stack trace with that error message; try looking through that and find which method is throwing the exception (its probably the top-most method in the list). That will tell you precisely where the error is occuring. You can post the stacktrace if you like as well.

Comment: everything I put in the action is not executed

Comment: stacktrace http://upl.io/qbnitr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer because I don't know precisely how to solve your problem, but I can at least tell you where it is and hopefully give you an idea so you can figure out the rest.

Based on the stacktrace, it looks like you're using the [`CanCan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem. Apparently, it is intercepting the request before it gets to your action, as evidenced by this portion of the stacktrace:

```
...
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'<- here
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:116:in `find_resource'
...
```

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this library. However, after browsing their [wiki page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki), I was able to find this information regarding [conditionally checking authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization).

According to that page, you might be able to get away with something like this:

```
skip_authorization_check :only => [:add_speaker, :remove_speaker]
```

I assume doing this will suppress `CanCan`'s authorization check, thus preventing your error.

Comment: Also note: since I am not familiar with `CanCan`, I cannot tell you whether this is a bad practice. Hopefully it is acceptable, but let me know.